# How to send a email to related list of an case object?

Tags: trigger, custom-object, workflow, custom-field

We have two objects Case and PO. A Button has been created in the case object,we are having lookup relationship between case and PO object in which the Case is the master and  with the PO as child. On the button click on the case object should fetch the records detail from the Child object (PO) and automate mail based on the mail id provided in the PO object record field which is a contact lookup field that hold the sender mail id. Can any advice me on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Lavanya

Comment: You need to a) invoke some Apex from the custom button then b) use SOQL to query the PO and Contact then c) use Messaging.sendEmail to send the email. Which part of this do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: Or you could use custom button with a) Javascript+AJAX to fetch the Case > PO > Contact.email; b) update Case with result of a) + boolean 'is_ready_for_PO_based_email__c'; c) workflow that executes when boolean is true and sends email alert + field update to turn off the boolean.